# Not able to bind mount a folder into a docker container , in windows

Tags: docker, airflow, docker-volume

```
docker run -v C:\Users\prashant\Desktop\letsgoairflow\mnt:\usr\local\airflow --rm -p 8080:8080 -d airflow-basic
```

I have created the appropriate host path but still the mnt folder doesn't get populated even though the command runs without an error

Comment: Try replacing the \ characters of the target mount destination with `/` characters, such as `C:\Users\prashant\Desktop\letsgoairflow\mnt:/usr/local/airflow`. Your docker container presumably uses a Unix based OS, which use `/` as the directory separator instead of \.

Comment: thanks a lot man this solved my issue , this error literally took 1 day to fix